# onChange not fired with object from ReactDOMServer.renderToString

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.10.2/umd/react.development.js" integrity="sha256-Fy0+oh76u+dih9imNzr0Ka1RHbVKV8o4nR+p8s6wTXE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.10.2/umd/react-dom-server.browser.development.js" integrity="sha256-9RKwrcM4wRE4Y5OMBHdU2seQ9j3zkVTFPCZK7ivP+NI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js" integrity="sha256-FiZMk1zgTeujzf/+vomWZGZ9r00+xnGvOgXoj0Jo1jA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id='show'></div>
<div id='ctl'></div>
<div><input oninput="update(this)" id='input2'/></div>
<script type="text/babel"  data-presets='react'>
function update(input){
    console.log('update')
    show.innerHTML=input.id+' value:' +input.value+'<br/>';
}

function getCell() {
    return ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<input onChange={(e)=>console.log(e)} id='input1'/>);
}
ctl.innerHTML=getCell();
</script>
```

I am using jsx for part of my application. I want to finally make `input1` and `input2` to have the same behavior. However, it seems even the simple `onChange` does nothing for the input above, I am confused by what's going wrong here.

Comment: Your onChange is only calling a console.log?

Comment: @ruby_newbie I imagine it finally will be something like `update(e.target)`, but now even `console.log` gives me nothing in the console.